# Embed .exe and .reg into VB.NET application

Tags: vb.net

If I have a file called file.reg and other called file.exe and I want to embed/add them into a VB.NET application and use `Process.Start()` to run them ... How to do that and.....

**NOTICE:** I don't want file.exe and file.reg to exists on the PC that will run the application!!!

I tried to add the files to the project resources and set Build to "Embedded Resource" of both files and set "Copy always" and use

`Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + "\file.reg"`

But still the files must be on the PC :(

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a good old virus :)

Comment: @duDE - not virus... I want to make edits to VLC plugin

Comment: You're trying to start the process by using Application.StartupPath which is a disk location. Take a look through this MS article which explains how to consume embedded resources: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/319292

Comment: @jonc -something simillar for VB.NET ?

Comment: That would be at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319291 which is linked to from the link I gave you - "For a Microsoft Visual Basic .NET version of this article, see 319291". Glad you found the solution anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% what I wanted: http://www.hc-kr.com/2016/07/vbnet-run-embedded-resources-files.html?m=1

Thanks for a StackoverFlow user for helping in a StackoverFlow chat room and giving me this link! :)